# Wordpress AMP version change logo link

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I have a wordpress site it's a mobile responsive site. And also have a google AMP version. In amp version when i click the header logo it's redirect to amp version. but i want to change the link redirect to none amp version site. how can i do it.

Comment: How do you have the AMP version, is it through a plugin? Does it use a theme ? etc... More details are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey if you installed amp plugin by Automattic you don't have to do anything by Default it links to the non-amp Home

If you installed amp for WP plugin AhmedKaludi , you can do it from their settings page , in their Advance section

Comment: i use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/) plugin and it works